# Chunking Results In Laravel Blade Failing Due To Callback

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to chunk the results of a laravel collection in my blade template to have 3 columns of records expanding to as many rows as needed. What I have is...

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->apps()->chunk(3) as $chunk)
    <div class="row row-grid gx-0">
        @foreach($chunk as $app)
            <a href="{{ $app->url }}" class="dropdown-item text-decoration-none p-3 bg-none">
                <div class="position-relative">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-fill position-absolute text-theme top-0 mt-n2 me-n2 fs-6px d-block text-center w-100"></i>
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-{{ $app->icon }} h2 opacity-5 d-block my-1"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="fw-500 fs-10px text-white">{{ ucfirst($app->alias) }}</div>
            </a>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

But I am getting the error `Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::chunk(), 1 passed in /app/storage/framework/views/7d3f05473ba9eb01ea58150355cc97e13e862587.php on line 1 and exactly 2 expected`. Taking a look at the Laravel source in Github it appears as a callback function is required which handles the looping for each chunk but this only really works if done from within PHP itself, within a blade template I cant figure out how to to a chunk with a callback. All the information I have been able to find online for Laravel blade chunking shows that this should be working.

My controller method is...

```
$userApps = Auth::user()->apps();
$chunk = ceil($userApps->count() / 3);
return view('apps', ['apps' => $userApps, 'appsChunk' => $chunk]);
```

Comment: You are right, it's the controller job to chunk the results, within the blade template it will be a little bit dirty, you will need to use @ php and @ endphp and put your code here, it's doable but still better do it on the controller side

Comment: Righto @Lk77, do you have any advice on how to refactor this to chunk in the controller instead and how I will need to change the blade by any chance. I have added my current controller method above.

Comment: Also i'm not very sure if what you expect from chunk method is really what the method do, it's seems you want to divide the results in three columns, and that's not what chunk is used for, it used to process X rows at a time

Comment: You're mistaking the Eloquent version of `->chunk($count, $callback)` with the Collection version `->chunk($count)`. Try `@foreach(Auth::user()->apps->chunk(3) as $chunk)`, as `->apps` and `->apps()` are 2 very different things 

Comment: Thats exactly what I want to do. I will have anywhere from 1 to 50 results in the apps collection and need to display then into a 3 column wide grid, i thought chunk would be the most efficient way to do this but if you have a better suggestion then by all means im all ears.

Comment: Well you could use chunk for that, with 3 arrays, and put the index 0 in array 0, the index 1 in array 1 and so on, but i'm not sure if it's very efficient

Comment: @Lk77 This is the correct approach, [the documentation even says so](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-chunk): *"This method is especially useful in views when working with a grid system such as Bootstrap. For example, imagine you have a collection of Eloquent models you want to display in a grid:"*. They simply are calling `->chunk()` on an Eloquent instance `->apps()` vs a Collection instance `->apps` or `->apps()->get()`

Comment: Well i would retrieve everything and use splitIn function 
 https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-splitin on the collection to split : ```$collection->splitIn(3);``` it but i guess the chunk version works aswell, i'm just afraid it will make `n/3` requests where `n` is the number of rows in the database, for 50 rows thats 16 sql requests

Comment: @Lk77 Yeah, for a lot of cases, loading first via the Controller is fine (if not preferred), but code called against `Auth::user()` will only be loaded once (since only 1 User can be logged in for any given session), so in the Controller or the View is generally acceptable. `$apps = Auth::user()->apps()->get(); return view('whatever', compact($apps));`, then `@foreach($apps->chunk(3) as $chunk)` is much longer than just calling `@foreach(Auth::user()->apps->chunk(3) as $chunk)`, and is just as, if not more, performant  Again, the main issue here is the `apps()` vs `apps`, not the approach.

Comment: Yeah you right there is a chunk function on the collection that does not the same thing as the chunk function on the builder

Comment: @Lk77 Yup, you got it  Also, the Collection version will not call _any_ queries, since the results have already been loaded into a Collection. Can't say for the Builder/Eloquent version, but I would hope it doesn't call 16 individual queries 